# R raster::crop() The upper boundary of my cropped raster is always horizontal- why?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to crop a large multipolygon shapefile by a single, smaller polygon. It works using st_intersection, however this takes a very long time, so I'm instead trying to convert the multipolygon to a raster, and crop that raster by the smaller polygon.

```
## packages - sorry if I've missed any!
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(fasterize)
library(sf)
```

```
## load files 
shp1 <- st_read("pathtoshp", crs = 27700) # a large multipolygon shapefile to crop
### image below created using ggplot- ignore the black boundaries!
```

[image]

```
shp2 <- st_read("pathtoshp", crs = 27700) # a single, smaller polygon shapefile, to crop shp1 by 
plot(shp2)
```

[image]

```
## convert to raster (faster than st_intersection)
projection1 <- CRS('+init=EPSG:27700')
rst_template <- raster(ncols = 1000, nrows = 1000, 
                       crs = projection1, 
                       ext = extent(shp1))

rst_shp1 <- fasterize(shp1, rst_template)
plot(rst_shp1)
```

[image]

```
rst_shp2 <- crop(rst_shp1, shp2)
plot(rst_shp2)
```

[image]

When I plot shp2, the upper boundary is flat, rather than fitting the true boundary of the shp2 polygon.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example (like in the R help files).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `raster::mask()` instead of `crop()`.  `crop()` uses the second argument as an extent with which to crop a raster; i.e. it's taking the bounding box (extent) of your second argument and cropping that entire rectangle from your raster.

Something important to understand about raster objects is that they are all rectangular.  The white space you see surrounding your shape are just NA values.

`raster::mask()` will take your original raster, and a spatial object (raster, sf, etc.) and replace all values in your raster which don't overlap with your spatial object to NA (by default, you can supply other replacement values).  Though I will say, `mask()` will likely also take awhile to run, so you may be better off just sticking with sf objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving to the "terra" package (faster and easier to use than "raster").

Here is an example.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))[4]

x <- crop(r, v)
plot(x); lines(v)
```

As edixon1 points out, a raster is always rectangular. If you want to set cells outside of the polygon to NA, you can do

```
x <- crop(r, v, mask=TRUE)
plot(x); lines(v)
```

In this example it makes no sense, but you could first rasterize

```
x <- crop(r, v)
y <- rasterize(v, x)
m <- mask(x, y)

plot(m); lines(v)
```

I am not sure if this answers your question. But if it does not, then please edit your question to make it reproducible, for example using the example data above.